Excel, How to use "OFFSET" on the result of a "MAKEARRAY"
I generate a matrix with "MAKEARRAY" and I would like to be able to recover a submatrix of this matrix. I was thinking of using "OFFSET" but apparently it only works on range or cell.
I tried this :
=LET(data;MAKEARRAY(2;2;LAMBDA(row;col;row+col));OFFSET(data;;;1;1))

But i get "#value" as a result (this is rather normal because we cannot use OFFSET with a matrix)
Offset Documentation

You could do something with CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS()) and SEQUENCE() but its a bit ugly.

If you want to control the width and height like you using in your OFFSET() you can wrap TAKE() around your data variable.

You could use the implicit intersection logic as well per your output as it seems: =LET(data,MAKEARRAY(2,2,LAMBDA(row,col,row+col)),@data)

I agree, even if you just lazily replace offset with index(data, 1, 1) your formula would work. but OFFSET's 365 twin is drop and take. e.g. DROP(TAKE(data, offset_row+height, offset_col+width), offset_row, offset_col) is equivalent to OFFSET(range,offset_row,offset_col,height,width)

I didn't know about these functions, which are very useful, thank you! Btw, I noticed that if we reversed "TAKE" and "DROP" we had less calculation to do =LET(array;B24:F32;x;1;y;1;width;3;height;3;TAKE(DROP(array;x;y);width;height))

Yes. Thanks! Reversing drop and take is much cleaner.

Another solution using the INDEX function:
Semi-colon convention:
=LET(
   array; A1:B4; row_offset; 1; col_offset; 1; 
   IFERROR(
     INDEX(
       array; 
       row_offset + SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)); 
       col_offset + SEQUENCE(1; COLUMNS(array))
     );""
   )
 )

Comma convention:
=LET(
   array, A1:B4, row_offset, 1, col_offset, 1, 
   IFERROR(
     INDEX(
       array, 
       row_offset + SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)), 
       col_offset + SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(array))
     ),""
   )
 )


Thank you for this second example which works really well too, do you know which one is the fastest (performance level) ? (between your's and DS_London)

do you know which one is the fastest (performance level) ? (between your's and DS_London) I'm not sure.

You could use a combination of CHOOSEROWS and CHOOSECOLS with SEQUENCE to define a generic slice using Top Left and Bottom Right:
=LAMBDA(m,tlr,tlc,brr,brc,CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(m,SEQUENCE(1+brr-tlr,,tlr)),SEQUENCE(1+brc-tlc,,tlc)))


m = input matrix
tlr = top left row
tlc = top left column
brr = bottom right row
brc = bottom right column

